# TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str' Line 15?

Tags: python

Okay I'm trying to figure this out and coming up with nothing. I'm pretty sure I'm just having a "duh" moment and as soon as someone else sees my problem I'm going to feel dumb but I'll ask anyways! I haven't gotten the error I've gotten before so I'm not even sure how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated! :D

```
def main():
    # Variables
    total_sales = 0.0

    # Initialize lists
    daily_sales = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
     days_of_week = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', + \
                     'Thursday', 'Friday','Saturday']

    for index in range(7):
        daily_sales[index] = float(input('Enter the sales for ' + \
                                     days_of_week[index] + ': '))

    for number in daily_sales:
        total_sales += number

    # Display total sales
    print ('Total sales for the week: $', + \
       format(total_sales, ',.2f'), sep='')

# Call the main function.
main()
```

Comment: You never need a `\` inside of parentheses `( ... )`, brackets `[ ... ]`, or braces `{ ... }`. In fact, I've seen it recommended you flat out never use `\`, and use parentheses around an expression instead.

Comment: @AmberHolcombe Could you please check if my answer solves your problem, if you could you please validate my answer?

Comment: @AmberHolcombe Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to replicate the error you are getting but from you code I can see that you want the user to enter sales for each day and get the total. Here is a simple way on how I would do it

```
def main():
    days_of_week = [
        'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday',
        'Saturday'
    ]

    # use a list comprehension to generate a list of entered values
    total = [float(input('Enter the sales for %s: ' % a))
             for a in days_of_week]

    # use sum function to calculate the total in the list
    print "Total sales for the week: $%s" % sum(total)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is:

```
print ('Total sales for the week: $', + \
   format(total_sales, ',.2f'), sep='')
```

Specifically, the parts left here:

```
                                      + \
   format(total_sales, ',.2f')
```

That line continuation `\` at the end (unnecessary given the parens, but removing it wouldn't help) means you're doing `+format(total_sales, ',.2f')`. `format` returns `str`, and `str` doesn't implement unary `+` (because unary `+` is for mathematical expressions).

The fix is to just get rid of the `+`:

```
print ('Total sales for the week: $',
       format(total_sales, ',.2f'), sep='')
```

You could also simplify a bit using the `str.format` method:

```
print('Total sales for the week: ${:,.2f}'.format(total_sales))
```